# no possibility to ping local adress

Tags: networking, router, openvpn, ping

I have a Mikrotik router in my network
and two subnetworks set: 10.10.0.x and 192.168.88.x
Everything is working fine besides address 10.10.0.1
I can ping each host beside that one.
It is my openvpn host - I can ping it from outside network but not from local.
I can ping rest addresses from subnetwork ie 10.10.0.2 etc
Any ideas what might be set incorrectly?

[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTfKF.png)

Thanks

Should I specify something more ?

Comment: Does,the router use this Ip (as well)

Comment: no, router has two addresses 192.168.88.1 and 10.10.0.103

Answer (score 0):

ok,
so I deleted an related record in IP/ARP 
everything works